# Twilio with Salesforce Integration SSO Login

Tags: twilio

I am not able to paste the downloaded salesforce Certificate from my laptop to Twilio SSO X.509 CERTIFICATE section.
I have followed the correct steps as mentioned in the below docs:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/setup/sso-configuration/salesforce
Please help me paste the certificate as there is no option to upload the file in the Twilio SSO config page for X.509 CERTIFICATE.

Comment: What do you mean that you can't paste the certificate? What exactly is going wrong? Can you show me a screenshot, or even video of what you are trying to do and how it fails?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.